# Does \w also match numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would expect that this

```
var r = new RegExp('\\s\\@[0-9a-z]+\\s', 'gi');
```

applied to this string

```
1 @bar @foo2 * 112
```

would give me

```
1 * 112
```

bit instead it results in

```
1 2 * 112
```

so it looks like `@[0-9a-z]+`is not matching the number.

Surely I'm getting something wrong but I can't figure what.

This is in javascript - Firefox 49.0

Comment: ___applied to this string___ ??

Comment: Try `.replace(/\s*@[0-9a-z]+/gi, '')` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/60acDL/1)). Actually, I can't repro, could you please show a snippet of your code?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub - The main question... _"Does \w also match numbers?"_

Comment: (run hides in embarrassment)

Comment: @simone: any feedback on the 3 answer you received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly rigged this up which should do what you want.

```js
var string = "1 @bar @foo2 * 112";

var matches = string.replace(/\s@\w+/gi,"");

console.log(matches)
```

I could not reproduce your results with that regex, but I did find the final \s would stop the matching of @foo2.

```js
var value = "1 @bar @foo2 * 112";
var matches = value.match(
     new RegExp("\\s\\@[0-9a-z]+\\s", "gi")
);
console.log(matches)
```

This is because the regex can not then match the space in front of @foo which is required as part of the match. I hope this code solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `\w` does match latin numbers. `\w == [A-Za-z0-9_]`

Assuming you want to remove `@fooX`, you can use:

```js
console.log("1 @bar @foo2 * 112".replace(/\s@\w+/g, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

"\w" Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore). Only matches low-ascii characters (no accented or non-roman characters). Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_]
Best source to learn : [www.regexr.com](http://regexr.com)